# Which is the correct architecture for an intel xenon 5215 processor

Tags: server, system-installation, 64-bit, intel, architecture

I want to install ubuntu server 20.04 on a server with 64-bit intel architecture, the proccesor is an  intel xenon 5215. According to the instaltion guide I should use amd64 (Intel/AMD 64-bit) version https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/installation . However, the available options in the download page are for AMR, Power and s90x architectures.

https://ubuntu.com/download/server

What architecture do I choose?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to [Get Ubuntu Server | Download | Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/server) webpage, and click the *Option 2 - Manual server installation* button.
2. This will bring up a new screen. Click the green *Download Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS* button.
3. A pop-up window will open saying You have chosen to open: **ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso**. Click the *Save File* radio button and then click *OK*.